# How to set fixed width of a bar chart column using apex chart react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to set the column width of a bar chart using apex chart. Fox example, each column should be 50px width, Here is my try:

```
options={{
        plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                        distributed: true,
                        columnWidth: "80%",
                        barHeight: "20%",
                    },
                },
                yaxis: {
                    labels: {
                        minWidth: 0,
                        maxWidth: 50,
                    },
                },
            }}
```

and there is the codesandbox links: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-apexcharts-color-forked-27nw6r?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set config:

```
{
        plotOptions: { 
          bar: { 
            columnWidth: '100%' 
          } 
        }
      }
```